# IntelliJ Main Class Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mainclass

I am receiving an error that states that I need to specify a main class. As I am new to Java and IntelliJ I do not know what to specify. Here is an example that I am working on:

```
public class Grades
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int grade1 = 95;     //first grade
        int grade2 = 88;     //second grade
        int grade3 = 76;     //third grade

        //calculate average
        int avgGrade = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3)/3;

        //print results
        System.out.print("Average = ");
        System.out.println(avgGrade);
    }//end of main method
}//end of class
```

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error? How do you run the program? In an IDE like IntelliJ, you can usually just click on the file and say "Run".

Answer (score 0):

A `main` class is one that contains an [entry-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java) (in Java, that's your `main` method). So your `main` class is `Grades`.

Comment: It is still not working, as it states Warning: Class 'Grades' cannot be found in 'module'

Comment: Is your `Grades` class in a package? If so, use the fully-qualified class name.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Run menu, select Configurations, go to the Configuration tab and set the Main class field to `Grades`.